# HTML Search bar redirecting to search page with the entered input

Tags: html

I have an index and a search page(where results from searches are displayed). Both have basic code for a search box

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" class="Search" name="search" value="<%=h params[:search] %>"/>
<input type="submit" class="myButton" name="submit" value="Search" /><br><br></form>
```

What I don't know how to do is make the search box from the index page to open the search page with the input written from the index page.

index page -> write something in the search bar in index page -> sends you to the search page with the output from the search.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action attribute to your form.

For instance:

```
<form method="get" action="search.html">
```

Comment: That's how I post them, but he didn't mention javascript.